# Non-realime rendering in browser (Flash)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d, rendering

What open-source libraries you can suggest to make non-realtime (photorealistic) 3D rendering in Flash Player? I want to use browsers as nodes to render scenes, and send result back to the server after finishing rendering.

Comment: I think you should use specialized software to render, not Flash player, it is an extra emulation layer over CPU which is plainly not needed in terms of performance. Also, rendering is an uninterruptible process, while Flash program needs to eventually release code flow to process frames, or else it risks being terminated. There might be libraries, although I doubt its need.

Comment: Vesper is right, but I think it can be done. The problem is that you can't use stage3d for it, as you can't access rendered stage3d content. So it would be really slow.

Comment: @Vesper One can render in a secondary worker and let the primary one tick.

@csomakk It is possible to grab rendered content in a bitmap data. Sure, it`s slow but it would be done only once after rendering, so no big deal